# segmentation fault knapsackproblem

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

**I wrote this knapsack problem solution in c++ however when I run it, it gives me segmentation fault**
I have tried everything and my compiler will always give me the segmentation fault error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int knapsack(int v[],int w[],int n,int W)
{
    int V[n][W];
    for(int i = 0; i<=W;i++)
    {
        V[0][i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<=W; j++)
        {
            if(w[i]<=W)
            {
                V[i][j] = std::max(V[i-1][j], v[i]+V[i-1][j-w[i]]);
            }
            else
            {
                V[i][j] = V[i-1][j];
            }

        }
    }
    return V[n][W];
}

int main()
{
    int v[4] = {10,40,30,50};
    int w[4] = {5,4,6,3};
    int n = 3;
    int W = 10;

    std::cout<<"item value:"<<knapsack(v,w,n,W);
}
```

Comment: Educated guess: Loop conditions are usually `counter < length`, not `<=` because the last index of an array is `length - 1`.

Comment: `int V[n][W];` This requires a support for _variable-length arrays_, which is a non-standard construct in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use VLAs. The size of an array must be known at compile time, else it's not standard C++. Those are compiler extensions that are not portable and introduce some hidden costs.
2. Array indices go from 0 to length-1. in you loop

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i<=W;i++)
   ```

   `i` can reach `W`, then `V[0][W]` is out of bounds which causes the seg fault. You have to use `<` instead of `<=`:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < W; i++)
   ```
3. `n` should probably be 4, if it's meant to represent the size of the array, a `std::vector` would make your life easier here, because a vector knows it's size
4. In general don't use C-style arrays or raw pointers at all in this day and age, use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
int V[n][W];
for(int i = 0; i<=W;i++)
{
    V[0][i] = 0;
}
```

Note that V's indexes go from `V[0][0]` to `V[0][W-1]`. Your for loop will try to read `V[0][W]`.

The same error is repeated in other places. Your end condition in your for loops should be `<` (strictly less) instead of `<=` (less or equal than).